# How do I click on a specific google search result using Selenium with Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am new to Selenium and coding. I have been trying to go to navigate to twitch.tv. using xpath but it gets stuck on the webpage. I don't really understand how parsing with a list to find it works.

```
package Demo_Test;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;

//C:\Users\d-syeed.farrakhan\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.33.0-win64

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class First {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\d-syeed.farrakhan\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.33.0-win64//geckodriver.exe"); 
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
//Initiating your chromedriver
System.out.println("Gave driver some space");
//Applied wait time
System.out.println("Give it some time");
//maximize window
System.out.println("Max that window please!");
//open browser with desried URL
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
System.out.println("go to google!");

driver.findElement(By.id("APjFqb")).sendKeys("Twitch.tv");
System.out.println("type in twitch");

driver.findElement(By.id("APjFqb")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div[11]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/span/a"));
System.out.println("google search twitch");
//closing the browser
System.out.println("Bye World");
}
}
```

I was expecting to reach the twitch webpage. I tried using a list to parse the page for it but it didn't work because I didn't understand it. Also I don't understand the format of the consolidated or shortned xpaths that aren't like the ones in the code.